# Should I ask (and eventually answer) a possibly opinion-based about an intrinsically ambiguous topic?

Tags: discussion

I was going to write (and eventually answer) a question about best practices in writing percussion parts for an orchestral ensemble, as I've seen some questions here and elsewhere dealing with such common doubts.
But then I stopped and realised that I don't know if I should.

I am a professional percussionist. As such, I know too well about the issues most of my fellow musician face when dealing with badly written parts.

I know that such questions that may lead to opinion-based answers are generally considered off topic, but I *really* feel that we may need a question dealing with writing percussion parts (and, possibly, a drum related one), which may be used as a reference to composers, even as a duplicate source for similarly related questions.

I also worked as a programmer, and I still code in my spare time, sometimes for my profession, even if indirectly: as you may see from my profile, I've got some experience in stackoverflow.com as contributor both in answering and in maintenance. So, I do know that we shouldn't ask such questions.

Still, to my opinion, this is quite a specific matter, even if controversially wide.
I'm not talking about generic and extremely ambiguous aspects like "best programming practices", or something that would conceptually make sense in softwareengineering SE as opposed to stackoverflow.

The problem with the world of percussion instrument is that it's as wide as it is specific, and its notation is an extremely detailed (as normally underestimated) aspect.

We also (luckily?) don't have a dedicated SE website for percussion, but I do believe that such a thread may be useful for "grouping" similar questions by marking them as duplicates or, at least, use it as a reference in comments. I also doubt that simple tagging would suffice.

As a player/composer/arranger, I would find this greatly helpful (at least as a starting point, besides narrowed research), but, as a SE user, I also realise how controversial such post would be.

Would it be right to ask such a question?
Do you have suggestions about *proper* ways to ask it, so that it doesn't become a black hole for ambiguous and extremely opinion based answers?

Comment: As a starting point, does such a resource already exist online at some other freely accessible site?

Comment: Also, IMO, "opinion-based" doesn't mean it can't be answered factually. Rather, it means that the question is likely to accumulate opinion-based answers (in addition to any fact-based ones).

Answer (score 3):

Best practices in writing percussion parts for an orchestral ensemble is a huge subject. There are already whole books on percussion writing, e.g. Samuel Solomon's book ["How to Write for Percussion"](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/dp/0199920362). Rather than trying to cover everything in one question it's better to concentrate on specific questions as they come up (such as recent questions on a particular cymbal part or on bowing vibraphone).

If there are specific things that you feel are not well covered elsewhere you could also ask your own questions and answer them.

Questions on best-practice will always have a small opinion-based component. Even experts can't always agree on the exact details, but there are mostly only a couple of good ways to do something.